# Why does a 4 year old Lenovo Thinkpad laptop suddenly start to violently vibrate?

Tags: hard-drive, fan, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad laptop about 4 year old. While using it, it suddenly starts to make noises and vibrate violently.

We thought the issue was with the fan so we had the fan removed, cleaned and put back but still issue persists.

I still cannot figure out what the issue is.

Here is [a video](https://youtube.com/shorts/9Tz_QClvhYk) of the laptop during the issue. What can be the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you clarify whether the laptop has a hard drive or SSD?

Comment: Laptop has only ssd

Comment: Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: If there is no HDD in there, then there must be some other mechanical device; plausibly that whining noise is broken bearings. Vibration on the other hand... maybe still the fan. Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: @DavidPostill I did they told it would be dust and they removed the fan , cleaned it and stuck it inside again... maybe I will have to go to another one..

Comment: Yes, replace the fan.

Comment: The repair shop didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Don't just clean the fan and put it back. Get it replaced. Dust can be a problem, but if the fan bearing is gone then removing the dust will do nothing.

Comment: Could it be a stuck CD or DVD? That’s what it sounds like to me.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 No it doesn't have a reader.

Comment: Could it be a prank? Someone could have switched Startup sound for one of these: https://www.soundsnap.com/tags/computer_fan  If volume is high, it'll vibrate the machine (just tested on my own laptop ;-)